# Missing DBconfig

Tags: php, mysql

I have download slots php script from github https://github.com/boomer121/slot-machine and I am trying to setup it.
Some things I made up to setup, but there are some files missing.
I stuck at database connection, DBconfig.php is missing and I do not know how to make call for database in it.
I figure out that database is called in some other files by:

```
 $db = DBconfig::get_instance();
 $user = $db->mysqli_fetch_array('SELECT * FROM users WHERE uid = \''.$uid.'\'');
```

I have try few ways to make class DBconfig in DBconfig.php but did not succeed.

Comment: `mysqli_fetch_array` => `query` - Fetch "after" you queried. `if (!$user) {
    trigger_error('query failed', E_USER_ERROR);
}`

Comment: Sorry if I am wrong but as I get from code what is needed is DBconfig class with database call which I do not know to write down. 
This part of code I put in question is from here https://github.com/boomer121/slot-machine/blob/master/User.php